# How to scale Firebase Database Quickstart, to be able to handle large number of users, and what it means by it making the post data more expensive?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase Database Quickstart 
https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/database

Under the description of the Data Model, it's mentioned
"This quickstart demonstrates a simple data model for a social application. While this data model uses some of the Firebase best practices, it has some known tradeoffs made for simplicity that would not scale to very large numbers of users.
The database has four "root" nodes:
users - a list of User objects, keyed by user ID. So /users//email is the email address of the user with id=.
posts - a list of Post objects, keyed by randomly generated push ID. Each Post contains the uid and author properties to determine the identity of the author without a JOIN-style query.
Posts contain a stars property which is a Map of user IDs to boolean values. If /posts//stars/ is true, this means the user with ID  has starred the post with ID . This data nesting makes it easy to tell if a specific user has already starred a specific post, but would not scale to large numbers of stars per post as it would make loading the Post data more expensive"

Appreciate if someone can explain what they mean by:
1-Would not scale to very large numbers of users.
2-Would not scale to large numbers of stars per post as it would make loading the Post data more expensive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to understand the current costs and limitations of firebase. The larger the size of DataSnapshot the more bytes it will download from the database. Total download bytes is directly translates to firebase billing cost. Let's take an example:

Let's say you have this database structure for storing stars for a post. `Post/<Post-ID>/stars/<User-ID>`. Your post has 20 stars then it will look something like this

```
Post:{
    postId:{
        stars:{
            user1:true,
            user2:true,
                ...
            user20:true
        }
    }
}
```

And the size of this snapshot is let's say 200 bytes. Now imagine your post gets popular and has 1 million stars. In this case your snapshot size will increase from 200 bytes to lets say 1 KB. And your snapshot will look something like this:

```
Post:{
    postId:{
        stars:{
            user1:true,
            user2:true,
                ...
            user1000001:true
        }
    }
}
```

Now for this post, it will take more data to download plus it will take more time to display the number of stars for that post.

There are many ways to make it efficient. You can take help of realtime database triggers of firebase cloud functions and make a better structure.

That's the answer of your second question.

Now for the First question you should understand the firebase's limitations and billing calculations. [Understand Firebase Limitation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/limits). To make a better database architecture and scalability firebase provides us with multiple database instances [Scale with Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/sharding).

Hope it helps!